# Get list of current hot indexes in elasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

1. Is there a way to get a list of hot indexes (available for writing) in elasticsearch?
2. if yes, is there a way to get that list associated only with specific alias?

Edit:

If we can improve on this point then even better:
better solution without the need to iterate all over the indexes to find the hot indexes. but getting straight away only the hot indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `GET _cat/aliases/alias-name?format=json` and keep only the entries with `is_write_index: true`. That will get you the list of indices associated to the specific alias and currently being written to.

Comment: so there is no way to add a query with "is_write_index: true"? I ll have to iterate the list ?

Comment: also can I implement it in Java ? if yes, do you know how?

Comment: Yes, you can make that call using the [Java client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/index.html) easily and iterate over the results to only get what you need

Comment: you mean that I ll have to use java low level client, right ?

Comment: Yes, indeed, the low level client provides support for making that call. Which version are you on?

Comment: Soon I ll upgrade to the latest version. (currently 7.13.1)